# Handlers with Syncano requests

Tags: android, syncano

I am using Syncano as in my chat application.
Currently I am retrieving contact list stored on Syncano to populate my contact list screen.
But due to varying delays in the response, sometimes the screen is drawn with no contacts.

Is there a handler (or any method) that can detect when the response is complete so it initiate the screen drawing after that?

Comment: Can you provide some code you currently have for this? (Excluding private API details of course)